# Using the mod "Armoa's Core 1997's Dimensional World" How do i change the mining world "y" height?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

Ok, so I want the Mining World to be at `Y: 256` so people can only dig down. Plus, this will allow for more ores to be generated. How can I increase the `Y` Cord to do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so first you need go to the `config` folder in your `.minecraft`. Then, once in the folder, go to `aroma1997`'s folder. Then, go to `Aroma1997sDimension.cfg`, open this using some kind of text editor. Scroll down to where it says `I:worldHeight=80`, just change the number to `256`. If you want to change the ore density, go to where it says `I:oreDensity=1` and chang ethe number to `5` or lower.